# how can i delete kubernetes's pvc

Tags: kubernetes

i try delete pvc but i cant

```
kubectl get --all-namespaces pvc

NAMESPACE      NAME            STATUS        VOLUME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
test-logging   es-local-pvc1   Terminating   es-local-pv1   450Gi      RWO                           21d
```

Answer (score 2):

kubectl delete pvc es-local-pvc1

if you see any problem, most likely that the pvc is protected from deletion.

```
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
```

you need to edit the pvc and verify that finalizers under metadata is set to null using the below patch.

```
kubectl patch pvc <pvc-name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

Then you should be able to delete the pvc

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should try 
`kubectl delete pvc es-local-pvc1 -n test-logging`

If it doesnt help, then I absolutely agree with solution provided by @PEkambaram.
Sometimes you can resolve this issue only by patching [pv](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and [pvc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) finalizers.

You can list finalizers by

`kubectl describe pvc PVC_NAME | grep Finalizers`

and change by

```
kubectl patch pvc <pvc-name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

Btw,the same could happen with PV also, ans you can do the same:

```
kubectl patch pv PV-NAME -p ’{“metadata”:{“finalizers”:null}}’
```

Github [PV is stuck at terminating after PVC is deleted](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69697#issuecomment-489876217) post also can help in situation when you need to patch pod

```
kubectl patch pvc db-pv-claim -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
kubectl patch pod db-74755f6698-8td72 -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```